# Dynamically set Google Maps API key in Xamarin forms

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, google-maps-api-2

I am working for a product based company. We are building Xamarin form apps for our customers. We would like to have separate Google Maps API key for our customers. But as per the documentation this can only be done in Manifest files.

We would like to set this key dynamically, as our app is available on Play Store and based on customer, we will decide the key.

Kindly let me know how can we achieve this.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. Google requires the Maps API Key to be in the Manifest file and from there there's no way to replace it once the apk is created.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do is to have a "tag" for each of the customers and call google analytics at the same time that you are calling the Google Map.. Then you can run a report on Google Analytics based on the tag